# Exchange-correlation potential for one electron system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, density-functional-theory

For classical ion, the DFT solution of the ground-state electronic system is given by
$$
\left[-\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2 + V_H(\mathbf{r}) + V_{ei}(\mathbf{r}) + V_{xc}(\mathbf{r})\right]\psi(\mathbf{r}) = \varepsilon \psi(\mathbf{r})
$$
where $V_{ei}(\mathbf{r})$ is the Coulomb potential for electron-ion interaction, $V_{xc}(\mathbf{r})$ is the potential due to the exchange-correlation energy, and $V_H(\mathbf{r})$ is the classical Hartree potential defined as
$$
V_H(\mathbf{r}) = \int\frac{n(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r'}|}\ \mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{r'}.
$$

Based on many references that I read, I get an impression that the density in the Hartree potential is the **total density from all orbitals**, not the total density of electrons in other orbitals. That means even if there is one electron, the classical Hartree potential should be non-zero.

By rewriting the exact Schrodinger equation for one electron which is,
$$
\left[-\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2 + V_{ei}(\mathbf{r})\right]\psi(\mathbf{r}) = \varepsilon \psi(\mathbf{r}),
$$
does that mean for systems with only one electron, $V_{xc}(\mathbf{r}) = -V_H(\mathbf{r})$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the electronic Hartree potential is accounting for the average electrostatic repulsion between the electrons, it is indeed completely spurious for a one electron system, as there should be no electron-electron interaction whatsoever.

And yes, using an exchange-correlation potential that exactly cancels the Hartree potential is the perfect choice for a one electron system.

Since $V_{xc}=-V_H$ would be a poor choice for multi-electron systems, meta-exchange-correlation funtionals take advantage of the fact that one can approximately deduce from the Kohn-Sham kinetic energy density whether the charge density is locally composed mostly of a single orbital or of several ones. For the limit of single orbitals, these meta-exchange-correlation functionals are typically constructed such that the exchange energy cancels the Hartree energy of the hydrogen atom (see e.g. page 8 of [Sun, Ruzsinszky, & Perdew "Strongly Constrained and Appropriately Normed Semilocal Density Functional" arXiv:1504.03028v3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.03028v3.pdf)).